# How to get json format below in php

Tags: php, json, jqbargraph

I am New to PHP I want to generate a json code like this

```
[{"section_name": "Section A","data": [{"value": "2"},{"value": "0"}]}, {"section_name": "Section B","data": [{"value": "1"},{"value": "0"}]}]
```

In this I am retrieving `"section_name"`,`"value"` from database.

Here the concept is get values from database to display a bar chart, based on classes and sections.

But my template I had chosen, I have to get the values(no. of students in a class & section) for individual sections, as shown in below bar chart.

My PHP Code:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select class_name as label from class ") or     die(mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $rows1[] = $row1;
}
$data1 = json_encode($rows1);

$result2 = mysql_query("select s.section_name as sectionname, 'data' as data from section s") or die(mysql_error());

$result3 = mysql_query("select (select count(*)as c from student_status ss where ss.section_id=s.section_id and ss.class_id=c.class_id) as value from section s, class c order by s.section_name asc ") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 1)
{
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $rows2[] = $row2;
    }
    $data2 = json_encode($rows2);

    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
    {
        $rows3[] = $row3;
    }
    $data3 = json_encode($rows3);


}
```

My JSON CODE:

```
"categories": [
            {
                "category": <? echo $data1 ?>/*[
                {
                    "label": "1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "TWO"
                },
                {
                    "label": "3"
                }
                ]*/
            }
        ],
        "dataset": /*<? echo $data2 ?>*/[
            {
                "sectionname": "Section A",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "value": "2" //class 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "1" //class 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "sectionname": "Section B",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "value": "" //class 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": ""  //class2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Hope you guys understand question.

[image]

Comment: show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Please give us your sample code

Comment: reply me I added my code

Answer (score 2):

If you are new with php, you should read `array` in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Then you can define an array like this

```
$arr = array(
   array(
       'section_name' => 'Section A',
       'data => array(
          array('value' => 2),
          array('value' => 0),
        )
   ),
  )
   //... other section
```

Then output json `echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: I am not a beginner. I don't know how to solve this particular block. Now I added my code above, kindly give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is used for array and `{"a": ..}` for associative arrays. Combining this two together and you could easily create this json structure.

```
array(
    array(
        "section_name" => "Section A",
        "data" => array(
            array("value" => "2"),
            array("value" => "0"),
        )
    ),
    // ...
)
```

Using `json_encode` gives you the wanted result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my code above kindly give me another suitable answer for the above question. Thank you.